# Project Intu "Intu Manager" does not connect

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, intu

I have tried to run Intu Manager according to the directions found here: https://rg-gateway.mybluemix.net/README.pdf without success. I have a valid & registered organization and group, and am able to log into Bluemix and access resources. However, when I fire ups Intu Manager it first says "Registering com outer to Intu Gateway for authorization", and then displays an error message that says:

```
 Gateway Login FailOrganization does not have a parent associated with it
 The organization you are trying to sign into does not have a Parent Self    instance associated with it.
 Contact a system administrator to resolve this issue!
```

My Organization is TRI, and my group is TARS.

Any suggestions?